# Implementing web service with python on a virtual AWS instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rest, web-services

I need to implement a simple web service in python - it's my first experience with web services and REST APIs so I want to undertand what environment and tools would fit my needs. In my web service, I need to read some data from a database, do some simple logic, and support a GET call from another application (qualtrics).

I read and implemented a simple test web service with python using some useful blogs such as: [Building a Basic RestFul API in Python | Codementor](https://www.codementor.io/@sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq) 
but I need a real server so that I could call the API from external applications.

As I'm looking for a long term solution, I thought that using AWS EC2 instance may be a good solution for a server. I tried to implement it using some guidelines in blogs such as: [Deploy a Flask app on AWS EC2 | Codementor](https://www.codementor.io/@jqn/deploy-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2-13hp1ilqy2)

However, as I'm new to this and encountered some implementation/editing errors (e.g. handling of the wsgi file) and as I'm a windows person and the ubuntu stuff are not always easy to get used to, I was wondering what is the best framework for my needs? 
Is there any recomended flow in which I'll be able to implement my simple python code and connect it to a small server (either AWS EC2 instance or any other recomended one) in a more convenient way?

Another important note - I will need to run it only from time to time, this web server and web service should not be contantly live (that's why I thought that aws virtual instance would fit best).

Comment: This is quite broad, and likely off-topic, please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: @AMC I think its on topic. The question is about architecture in my view, and `amazon-web-services` tag says "Questions about programming and **architecture** are on topic."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, my recommendation would be to look at Elastic Beanstalk,  Fargate and API Gateway with Lambda.

You can use Elastic Beanstalk to easliy provision **out-of-the-box AWS environment** to host your python app in Flask with minimal configurations required:

- [Deploying a flask application to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html).

The other thing to consider would be to develop your python app as a **docker** container using, e.g., [tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask/) as the base image. This would allow you to easily work with in on your localhost, and then just move your image to AWS for hosting.

You can host it on [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) to save time on configuring container instances, or on [Beanstalk as well](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker.html) which also supports docker.

Yet other choice is to go fully **serverless** and develop your Python REST api using [API Gateway and lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html).

Comment: Thank you @Marcin! This is great! Is there any important limitation that I should be aware of in these options before I dive into them?

Comment: @user3017075 No problem. If the answer was helpful, an acceptance of it would be appreciated. Have no idea why it was down voted without giving a reason.